# Stored Procedure Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedure

Como hago para insertar registros en dos tablas relacionadas desde un stored procedured en laravel? Es decir, registro el usuario y luego recupero el id para insertar información en otra tabla.

Comment: un ejemplo seria `$user=new User();`, luego asignas sus valores `$user->name="un nombre"`, y despues lo guardas:`$user->save();`, una vez hecho eso, ya tienes el **id** respectivo es decir : `$user->id` ya tiene un valor

Comment: ahora deseas crear uno de forma directa, despues del **save** haces:`$user->rol()->create(["name"=>"nombre del rol"]);`, siendo **rol** una funcion de enlace ya sea `belongTo`, o `hasMany`.

Comment: Si, perfecto. De esta forma con el orm lo entiendo. La duda surge cuando registro llamando a la función de la siguiente forma: $save = DB::select('call funcionRegistrar'); Como retorno desde alli el id del usuario?

Comment: supongo que solo tendrias que hacer la funcion correspondiene retorne el **id** que deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo parecido al siguiente código :

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = "Paco"
$user->save(); // A partir de aqui User , ya tiene un id asociado

// Suponemos que usuarios --------> 1:N ---------> logs
// Por consiguiente desde User establecemos hasMany y desde Logs una belongsTo
$log = new Log();
$log->user->associate($user);
$log->save();
```

Una vez que guardamos , automáticamente el objeto que usamos para guardar , ya tiene asociado un nuevo `id` en la bases de datos , lo que tenemos que hacer en la nueva relación del nuevo objeto.

Tenemos que fijarnos que no podemos guardar un objeto como `logs` si en la base  de datos no tenemos antes al `user` ya que tenemos el problema que no existe un `id` que lo identifique y por encima tenemos un problema en la consistencia de la base de datos.

Comment: Si, con el metodo save() lo entiendo perfectamente. Ahora bien, trato de hacerlo de la siguiente manera: $registrar = DB::select('call registrarUsuario'); Como retorno el id desde allí?

Comment: Estas formando mal DB::select , tiene que ser lo que selecionas `DB::select('id')->table('users')->where('nombre','==','Paco');`, mira como se forman correctamente en https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Comment: Creo que no nos entendemos. Mira este ejemplo de procedimientos almacenados: DB::select('call store_procedure_function(?)', [$parameter]). Es eso lo que stoy utilizando.

Comment: Esto te puede servir ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497063/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-from-laravel